# Automate an Android game with Appium

Tags: python, android, appium

I'm working on a project to automate a Sudoku game on my Android device with Appium using Python.

I've automated the process of loading a new board. But the board has no child elements and appears as if it is just one element.

[image: Sudoku board]

How would I go about converting it to data that I can use?

Comment: i guess only with using OCR. Whomever wrote the board used frameworks that don't convert to data

Answer (score 0):

First try to get what's inside one element than you can store it in temp variable may be a list or map and can use to convert it into data

You can start by getting what's inside the element

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'your class name')]"));
for(WebElement element: listOfElements){
    System.out.println(element.getText());//if it is not empty you can store in in map and can use it later
```